# need help with the apex trigger

Tags: apex

**the trigger should be on account to check the assets and if ALL the Assets belonging to  product family = "bla bla "  had their status "Canceled" the trigger should update bla bla Account stage (API Name = Account_Status__c )  to "Cancel".**

below is a trigger I wrote but it doesn't work

```
trigger cancelAsset on Account (after update) {


    List<Asset> suite = [Select Id ,Status from Asset where Product_Family__c = '360 Suite']; 
    List<Asset> tech = [Select Id ,Status from Asset where Product_Family__c = 'Ad Tech']; 
    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){

        Integer z=0;
        for(Integer i=0 ; i<= suite.size() ;i++){
            if(suite[i].Status == 'Canceled'){
              z++;
            }
        }

        if (z == suite.size()){
            acc.Account_Status__c = 'Cancel';
        }
        update acc;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to sfse - you'll find that the root of your issue is that you are doing DML inside of a loop which is not correct. Review bulkification procedures and build up your updates in a collection, then update the collection outside of the for loop

Comment: can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a number of logical issues here.

### Wrong Trigger Object

Triggers run on change to records in the object they are declared `on`. Your trigger is intended to react to `Asset` data, but it is declared as a trigger `on Account`. It will run only when Accounts are updated, not when Assets are updated. I suspect this is the reason why you say it "doesn't work" - when you make changes to Assets, nothing happens. You'd need to write a trigger `on Asset` for that to happen.

### Unfiltered Queries

Your trigger assumes there is exactly one Account in your org, because its queries are not filtered.

```
List<Asset> suite = [Select Id ,Status from Asset where Product_Family__c = '360 Suite']; 
List<Asset> tech = [Select Id ,Status from Asset where Product_Family__c = 'Ad Tech'];
```

These queries will find every Asset in your org that have the appropriate Product Families. They don't do any filtering by the parent Account. If your trigger were operating in a context where more than one Account existed, the results would be incorrect.

It's very common to accumulate a Set of the related record Ids you are looking for, and then to filter a query that way. For example, if this were an Asset trigger, as above, you might do

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Asset a : Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(a.AccountId);
}

List<Asset> suite = [Select Id ,Status from Asset where Product_Family__c = '360 Suite' AND AccountId IN :accountIds]; 
List<Asset> tech = [Select Id ,Status from Asset where Product_Family__c = 'Ad Tech' IN :accountIds];
```

This ensures you are only querying the relevant information, which is important both for establishing correct behavior and respecting governor limits on SOQL rows and heap size.

## Logic

You need to determine whether each and every Asset associated with a specific Account meets criteria. First, then, you need to sort your queried Assets into a multi-map, a Map between Account Id and a list of Assets. Something like this could do it:

```
Map<Id, List<Asset>> assetMap = new Map<Id, List<Asset>>();
for (Asset a : listOfAssets) {
    if (!assetMap.containsKey(a.AccountId)) {
        assetMap.put(a.AccountId, new List<Asset>());
    }
    assetMap.get(a.AccountId).add(a);
}
```

This is a very general pattern you'll use over and over again.

Then, you'd need to iterate over the Accounts whose Assets you are processing, use their Ids to index into the Map, and then iterate over the list of Assets to determine whether criteria are met.

**Note**: There is another, advanced, solution here using Aggregate Queries, but I'm not sure it's useful to go there at this point.

### DML in a Loop

This is a classic problem in Salesforce development: you must always do your DML outside a loop to prevent consuming excess DML statements against your limit of 150 in a transaction. Remember that your trigger can be called with 200 (or more!) total Assets in a transaction.

Here, since you'd be updating Accounts, you'll probably want to maintain a `Map<Id, Account>`. As you find updates you need to make to an Account, you'll add each Account to the Map, with its Id as the key. Then, at the very end of your trigger, you'll do

```
update myAccountMap.values();
```

This ensures that

1. Your DML is bulkified;
2. You do not try to update the same record twice, which will net you an error.

### Recommendations

I strongly recommend you go complete the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) unit on Trailhead. The patterns involved take some getting used to, but you *need* to get acclimated to them to effectively develop triggers that work well and respect Salesforce governor limits.